# OneSignal Web Prompt customization

Tags: javascript, notifications, onesignal

How can I change background color of OneSignal buttons Web Prompt buttons?

I can not find this in their documentation.

Best,
 Bojan

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to change web prompt buttons without custom code. You can see these docs on adding your own custom link: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-custom-code-examples#section-custom-link-prompt

Make sure you are using the Custom Code Setup and not the Typical site setup.